# Get height of flexbox row

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container where the items on each row overflow, and go onto the next line. Each item is aligned to a baseline; hence, the rows can be of varying sizes depending on which items are on which row and how they align to their baseline.

The items are pictured below being centered at a baseline:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically get the row height? Or get the distance from each item's baseline to the top/bottom of the row?

I would like to do this so i can set a hover state around the items that allow the hover to stretch over the item and have the height go all the way to the top of each row, hence the hover for each items will look as follows:

[image]

my attempt:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/NickDueber-minted/pen/WGAvBd)

```css
/* on hover i want this to be a box around the item, and to have the top and the bottom of the border be touching the top/bottom of the row it is on */
.flex-item:hover {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}

/* so item doesn't move when not hovering */
.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

.flex-container {
  overflow: hidden;    position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.flex-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.flex-body-more {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1 longer title</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text more text more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the hover effect same height on all items by changing

```
.flex-container {
    align-items: baseline
}
```

to

```
.flex-container {
    align-items: strech
}
```

then I added the following lines to make items align vertically:

```
.flex-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

However, your original code is aligning these items "baseline" instead of "center".. I didn't figure out how to do that.

Hope this helps.

codepen: https://codepen.io/bottlecap/pen/pEgbNx

Answer (score -1):

Try plugging this into codepen.

html

```
    <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1 longer title</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text more text more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
      <div class="flex-img">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
      <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
    /* on hover i want this to be a box around the item, and to have the top and the bottom of the border be touching the top/bottom of the row it is on */
.flex-item:hover {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}

/* so item doesn't move when not hovering */
.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  outline:1px solid red;
  height:62vh;


}

.flex-container {
  overflow: hidden;    position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction:column;

}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.flex-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.flex-body-more {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```